# Can't open GeoJson with Python Sedona GeoJsonReader

Tags: python, pyspark

I am using Python's Apache Sedona to open a GeoJson file. I followed [this guide](https://github.com/apache/incubator-sedona/blob/master/binder/ApacheSedonaCore.ipynb). I follow every step for opening a GeoJson, but for the sake of clarity, this is what I did:

```
spark = SparkSession.\
    builder.\
    master("local[*]").\
    appName("Sedona App").\
    config("spark.serializer", KryoSerializer.getName).\
    config("spark.kryo.registrator", SedonaKryoRegistrator.getName) .\
    config("spark.jars.packages", "org.apache.sedona:sedona-python-adapter-3.0_2.12:1.1.0-incubating,org.datasyslab:geotools-wrapper:1.1.0-25.2") .\
    getOrCreate()
SedonaRegistrator.registerAll(spark)
sc = spark.sparkContext
amenity_file = 'example/2/amenity.geojson'
geojson_file = GeoJsonReader.readToGeometryRDD(sc, amenity_file)
```

The last line spits this:

```
22/03/25 16:52:17 WARN FormatMapper: [Sedona] The GeoJSON file doesn't have feature properties
```

However, I continued with the following line (just like in the example):

```
Adapter.toDf(geojson_file, spark).show()
```

But I got an error:

```
22/03/25 16:52:26 ERROR FormatMapper: [Sedona] com.fasterxml.jackson.core.io.JsonEOFException: Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for Object (start marker at [Source: (String)"{"; line: 1, column: 1])
 at [Source: (String)"{"; line: 1, column: 3]
22/03/25 16:52:26 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 8.0 (TID 8)
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.io.JsonEOFException: Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for Object (start marker at [Source: (String)"{"; line: 1, column: 1])
 at [Source: (String)"{"; line: 1, column: 3]
    at org.wololo.geojson.GeoJSONFactory.create(GeoJSONFactory.java:31)
    at org.wololo.jts2geojson.GeoJSONReader.read(GeoJSONReader.java:20)
    at org.wololo.jts2geojson.GeoJSONReader.read(GeoJSONReader.java:16)
    at org.apache.sedona.core.formatMapper.FormatMapper.readGeoJSON(FormatMapper.java:206)
    at org.apache.sedona.core.formatMapper.FormatMapper.readGeometry(FormatMapper.java:304)
    at org.apache.sedona.core.formatMapper.FormatMapper.call(FormatMapper.java:377)
    at org.apache.sedona.core.formatMapper.FormatMapper.call(FormatMapper.java:52)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike.$anonfun$mapPartitions$1(JavaRDDLike.scala:153)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitions$2(RDD.scala:837)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitions$2$adapted(RDD.scala:837)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:349)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:349)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:349)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:349)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:349)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:462)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:465)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.io.JsonEOFException: Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for Object (start marker at [Source: (String)"{"; line: 1, column: 1])
 at [Source: (String)"{"; line: 1, column: 3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportInvalidEOF(ParserMinimalBase.java:664)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserBase._handleEOF(ParserBase.java:486)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserBase._eofAsNextChar(ParserBase.java:498)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._skipWSOrEnd(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:2354)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser.nextFieldName(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:905)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.BaseNodeDeserializer.deserializeObject(JsonNodeDeserializer.java:249)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.JsonNodeDeserializer.deserialize(JsonNodeDeserializer.java:68)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.JsonNodeDeserializer.deserialize(JsonNodeDeserializer.java:15)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readTreeAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4254)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readTree(ObjectMapper.java:2711)
    at org.wololo.geojson.GeoJSONFactory.create(GeoJSONFactory.java:21)
    ... 32 more
22/03/25 16:52:26 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 8.0 (TID 8, works-mbp.lan, executor driver): java.lang.RuntimeException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.io.JsonEOFException: Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for Object (start marker at [Source: (String)"{"; line: 1, column: 1])
 at [Source: (String)"{"; line: 1, column: 3]
    at org.wololo.geojson.GeoJSONFactory.create(GeoJSONFactory.java:31)
    at org.wololo.jts2geojson.GeoJSONReader.read(GeoJSONReader.java:20)
    at org.wololo.jts2geojson.GeoJSONReader.read(GeoJSONReader.java:16)
    at org.apache.sedona.core.formatMapper.FormatMapper.readGeoJSON(FormatMapper.java:206)
    at org.apache.sedona.core.formatMapper.FormatMapper.readGeometry(FormatMapper.java:304)
    at org.apache.sedona.core.formatMapper.FormatMapper.call(FormatMapper.java:377)
    at org.apache.sedona.core.formatMapper.FormatMapper.call(FormatMapper.java:52)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike.$anonfun$mapPartitions$1(JavaRDDLike.scala:153)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitions$2(RDD.scala:837)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitions$2$adapted(RDD.scala:837)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:349)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:349)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:349)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:349)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:349)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:462)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:465)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.io.JsonEOFException: Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for Object (start marker at [Source: (String)"{"; line: 1, column: 1])
 at [Source: (String)"{"; line: 1, column: 3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportInvalidEOF(ParserMinimalBase.java:664)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserBase._handleEOF(ParserBase.java:486)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserBase._eofAsNextChar(ParserBase.java:498)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._skipWSOrEnd(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:2354)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser.nextFieldName(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:905)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.BaseNodeDeserializer.deserializeObject(JsonNodeDeserializer.java:249)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.JsonNodeDeserializer.deserialize(JsonNodeDeserializer.java:68)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.JsonNodeDeserializer.deserialize(JsonNodeDeserializer.java:15)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readTreeAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4254)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readTree(ObjectMapper.java:2711)
    at org.wololo.geojson.GeoJSONFactory.create(GeoJSONFactory.java:21)
    ... 32 more

22/03/25 16:52:26 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 8.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
```

EDIT: The file contains geometries... but it is inside an Array, then Struct. This is how it looks:

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "name": "amenity",
    "features": [
      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "feature_type": "amenity",
        "id": "1231312323f",
        "properties": {
          "accessibility": null,
          "address_id": "1231232312",
          "alt_name": null,
          "category": "elevator",
          "correlation_id": null,
          "hours": null,
          "name": null,
          "phone": null,
          "unit_ids": [
            "1232312",
            "123212"
          ],
          "website": null
        },
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [
            -121.8888997,
            37.3285715
          ]
        }
      }]}
```

UPDATE:

I tried also making up a very simple GeoJson and still throws the same error... I believe this is not to do with the GeoJsonReader:

```
{
  "type": "Point",
  "coordinates": [
      -105.01621,
      39.57422
  ]
}
```

Comment: are the geometries stored under a `features` key?

Comment: also -- post the error as *text*. People can't search for keywords within an image

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for the help... yes it is... I've updated the post with GeoJson and error in text

Comment: according to https://geojsonlint.com, that's not valid GeoJSON

Comment: That's right. I made a mistake copying the geojson content... I copied only the first child as the file is quite long. I edited the geojson in the post and shows as valid in geojsonlint.com...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@Paul H](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1552748/paul-h) pointed, the issue was related to the format. This was surprising as the file was an IMDF file verified by Apple... however, the GeoJsonReader renders it as corrupt. To solve the issue, filter the geojson from the 'Features' key.